# Does WEBSQL support Phonegap Apps on Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, web-sql

We're currently developing a iPhone/Android app with phonegap (and sencha touch), with a WEBSQL Database. Everything is working fine on the iOS and on all the Android versions, except for Ice Cream Sandwich. The problem until now has nothing to do with design, it's because the database is not loaded. The different tables are created, but without its content.

This gets me to the question, is WEBSQL supporting apps on Ice Cream Sandwich? Or did anyone have a similiar problem with this on ICS 4.0?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I have never used websql in ICS but would suggest you to move to other options available, such as using native sqlite available in the android device, which can easily be done using phonegap plugins, along with that websql have been deprecated since nov11, the drafting committee no longer works or maintains web sql and its performance is quite poor as compared to native sqlite