# WebSQL not working in ICS

Tags: android, cordova

I am using WebSQL for my PhoneGap application it is fine for GingerBread and Honeycomb but not working for ICS, I have checked the browser of ICS it supports WebSQL queries but i don't know whats wrong with a WebView of PhoneGap.

My code is:

```
openDatabase('shortName', '1.0', 'displayName', 5242880,function(){
    alert('db created');
});
```

Wondering if [WebSQL is deprecated in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311078/does-websql-support-phonegap-apps-on-ice-cream-sandwich)? or I need to make changes in above statement? or I need to use NativeDB plugin for ICS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION/FIXED : http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2012/03/my-phonegap-app-not-working-on-ics.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Android. It was a problem in Android 3.0 and seems to have cropped back up again in ICS. However, Bryce has [checked in a fix](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=commit;h=d2fc08959a7a4706b06c965c5129873abb03d262) for it in the 1.5.0 stream of PhoneGap/Cordova.

Comment: To make matters worse they bug appeared in only some Android 3.0 devices as different manufactures use different WebKit builds. For instance the Motorola Xoom with 3G was fine but Motorola Xoom WiFi only had the problem. There is no fragmentation here, more along.